# InjectionToken empty in prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I serve my app (ng serve), then ConfigurationService.coucou() return expected value.
But if I serve with --prod (ng serve --prod), window['config']['coucou'] in the constructor of AppModule, I get the expected value, but valueConfigurationService.coucou() return an empty string.

Any idea ?

AppModule :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ConfigurationService, COUCOU } from './configuration.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [ConfigurationService,{ provide: COUCOU, useValue: window['config']['coucou'] }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

configuration.service :

```
import { Injectable, Inject, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const COUCOU = new InjectionToken<string>('coucou');

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
    private _coucou: string;

    get coucou(): string {
        return this._coucou;
    }

    constructor( @Inject(COUCOU) coucou: string) {
        console.log('ConfigurationService.coucou : ' + coucou);
        this._coucou = coucou ? coucou : "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is here:

```
 this._coucou = coucou ? coucou : "";
```

It should look like this:

```
 this._coucou === coucou ? coucou : "";
```